# Logout functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, logout

How can I implement logout feature on my page so that user is redirected to a login page and is not allowed to view previous page?

```
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); is it enough for logout.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs the user out of their forms authentication.
    /// </summary>
    public void SignOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) {
if (!User.IsAuthenticated) {
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
}
```

Also I'd have that in a the master page.

Comment: Actually Paulie's answer is closer to being correct than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You also want to remove the session state after SignOut.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 

// Remove all session variables and destroy session
context.Session.RemoveAll();
context.Session.Clear();
context.Session.Abandon();
```

Comment: Personally, I don't think that Authentication is related to session, they can operate separately so Session may not need clearing for many people's purposes.  I know that is a common method though.

Comment: @PaulieWaulie I agree that they are separated. However, removing session after sign out is very common method that you can find in a lot of open source projects.

Comment: I wasn't criticising, just making a point for other people to consider :) .

Comment: @PaulieWaulie Sorry, I did not mean it. End of the day, we are just trying to help each other here. ;)

Comment: Thank you Win and PaulieWaulie